# Implementing "in portions" writable stream in node.js

Tags: node.js, stream, buffering, chunking

Here's some code

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const stream = require('stream');
const db = require('some-db-engine');

const readStream = fs.createReadStream('file.dat');
const transformStream = new stream.Transform({
    objectMode: true,
    highWaterMark: 1000,
    transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        const obj = { /* somehow transform input chunk to object */ };
        this.push(obj);
        callback();
    }
});
const writableStream = new stream.Writable({
    objectMode: true,
    highWaterMark: 1000,
    writev(chunks, callback) {
        /* chunks should be a buffered array of objects no more than 1000 items */
        db.query('dump all chunks () in one move', callback);
    }
});

stream.pipeline(
    readStream,
    transformStream,
    writableStream,
    (error) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error(error);
        } else {
            console.log('Success!');
        }
    }
);
```

What I want is `writableStream` to temporarily buffer incoming objects in portions by 1000 items, so the data is written to db in large portions at once. Instead `writev` method always recieves the array of exactly one element.
Of cource, I could implement my own internal buffer, just wondering am I missing something and if it's doable using native api: `highWaterMark` or `writable.cork()` or other?

**UPDATE**

While waiting I've come up with this solution so far:

```js
const createChunkedStream = (size) => {

    const queue = [];
    
    const process = (stream, end, chunk, callback) => {
        end || queue.push(chunk);
        if (queue.length >= (end ? 1 : size)) {
            stream.push(queue.splice(0));
        }
        callback();
    };

    return stream.Transform({
        transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
            process(this, false, chunk, callback);
        },
        flush(callback) {
            process(this, true, null, callback);
        }
    });

};
```

That can be used as

```js
stream.pipeline(
    readStream,
    transformStream,
    createChunkedStream(1000),
    writableStream,
    (error) => { /* ... */ }
);
```

Comment: The writable will buffer writes if the `writev` or `write` function is already executing. Thus writables tend to write a single chunk first, and buffer multiple operations for the subsequent writes (given that data flows into the writable faster than write() manages to drain it).

Comment: I guess using a Transform to buffer the chunks is the way to go. Maybe you could slightly tweak the flush behavior of the buffer: https://gist.github.com/jorgenkg/476294deda97da2f3baca4dd45889e82